# Текущее время на javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

Мне нужно сделать с помощью **javascript** так, чтобы в `<div class="dateandtime"></div>"` выводились **дата** и **время** (**число:имя месяца:год:часы:минуты:секунды**). Например: **1 января 2020 09:30:34**.
Буду благодарен, если ответите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('dateandtime')[0];

setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date;
  div.innerHTML = date.toLocaleString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="dateandtime"></div>
```

P.S. Сейчас поправлю месяц

Comment: У меня одна проблема: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined. Если запустить на codepen, то всё нормально.

Comment: @NIKOLAY ну проблема в том, что не может найти объект.

Comment: Ой, я просто поначалу поставил скрипт в <script>, а потом, из-за того, что текст чёрный, его еле-еле видно. Короче, всё нормально))) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @NIKOLAY это хорошо:)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность подключения сторонних библиотек — хорошее решение тот же [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), если нет, надо писать функцию, а лучше, объект, с прописанными названиями месяцев

```
function getFormatTime (date) {
    let month = ["января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"];
    return date.getDate() + " " + month[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear() + " " + ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

}